# Javascript Frameworks and Progressive Enhancement

Tags: javascript

It seems to me that js frameworks like Knockout take an "all-or-nothing" approach to development: you either adopt 100% javascript functionality or avoid using the framework altogether.

These frameworks seem unrealistic for the following scenarios:

1) SEO and/or Accessibility are a major concern
2) Existing web apps need js functionality layered into markup generated server side

What are your guy's thought? I'd really like the use a framework for all client-side code. My preference is knockout.js because the documentation and examples seem more solid than backbone's.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it'd affect SEO -- I mean, it's your responsibility to render the page with whatever you need Google to see.  Then use KO to add bells and whistles on top of that

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a good thing, that it is finally shifting to an all or nothing approach and these kinds of frameworks should only be used that way.

SEO: When building a Web application usually only registered users will have access to it. Therefore you will only have to optimize the public facing pages for SEO. Also, Google can now also crawl pages generated with JS.

Acessibility: This always brought up as a major concern, but unfortunately a lot of people don't really have an idea what this means. I have been working with a blind person for over a year and unlike developers thought at that time, a screenreader was quite able to handle JavaScript. If it is really important, offer different versions of your website targeted for certain disabilities (and for e.g. people with bad eyesight it is as simple as creating your CSS using em instead of px so that it still works in different zoom levels).

Existing apps: Extend your existing app, so that it can offer some kind of JSON REST webservice. This is the adjustment you have to make to use one of these frameworks. That way you can also easily create different versions (e.g. mobile) of your applications.

Comment: Thanks, Daff. Wonderful guidance. In my experience, however, there are public-facing portions of websites that have a high degree functionality that could be considered "apps". Take this site for example where most content is loaded server side and lots of js sugar is sprinkled on. I'd love to use a framework that enforces good SRP. However, it seems like I'd have to to double the work to scrape the site and load everything the framework requires into memory to make it work...

Comment: Yeah it is kind of a tradeoff. Not sure if there is a JavaScript framework that specifically targets this kind of compatibility. Basically for adding sugar you just need jQuery, not an MVC style framework.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've come to a decision based on feedback and on what I've been reading:

The biggest thing for me to consider is the cost (in time, resources, etc) of making progressive enhancements versus the benefit gained. PE seems to really slow down development of the front end since, in many cases, you are doing extra work to get things working both server and client side –even if server side code is re-used as much as possible. Also, PE tends not to work well with advanced client technologies and frameworks like json and knockout/backbone. Whether or not I’m working on document-based or app-based web project –in many cases I couldn’t really say which, seems like the lines blur a lot– here is my (new) decision tree:

```
If SEO is a concern, use progressive enhancement. Don’t rely on rumors that content loaded from javascript gets indexed!

If Accessiblity is a concern, use progressive enhancement. Just not ready for js in this arena.

If lack of javascript is a major concern, use progressive enhancement. Not sure if this should ever be a major concern anymore…

If it’s simple content where js will buy you little, just do the traditional web development

Otherwise, rely on clean javascript and server-side services, take and OO approach using a js framework!
```

Thanks!